# Check if mysql entry exits then DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I'm kind of a stuck in searching for a solution.

I need to check if an input data $coupon from the form (after "post" action) equals data in the existing MySQL table called Serial, in the row $Coupon. If those two entries match i need the one in table "Serial" removed (DELETED From). In the other case I need to display an Error, maybe like echo "The coupon number you've entered is invalid".

Now i have the following code, but it doesnt do the check.

```
$query4="SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM serial WHERE Coupon='$coupon')";
$result = mysql_query($query4);

if($result){
    echo "Bravo!";
}
else{
    "The coupon number you've entered is invalid";
    exit;
}
// Delete data from mysql
$query2="DELETE FROM serial WHERE Coupon = '$coupon'";
$result = mysql_query($query2); 

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Some info";
}
else {
die(mysql_error());
}
```

Appreciate any ideas greatly!

Answer (score 1):

You've created a race condition for yourself. The fact that the coupon exists when you run the  SELECT statement does not mean that it will exist when you run the delete statement, especially if this is a web app, or multi-threaded/multi-process.

The DELETE statement deletes rows from tbl_name and returns a count of the number of deleted rows. This count can be obtained by calling the ROW_COUNT() function.

Run your DELETE unconditionally, then use the ROW_COUNT to see if it was there and got deleted or wasn't ever there.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just do `SELECT 1 FROM serial...`

Then:

```
$result = mysql_query($query4);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

If it returns a row, you know it exists.  You can also add `LIMIT 1` to the query to make it faster.

---

By the way, your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: `if (mysql_num_rows($result)` returns a syntax error. What's next ?

Comment: @user2188208 oops, I was missing a closing paren.  Try again

Answer (score 0):

First of all phase out **mysql_*** functionality or you have bigger problems than checking the result. Your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Secondly, why do you need **EXISTS** in the first query at all?

Here is the solution in PDO:

```
 $query = 'SELECT 1 FROM serial WHERE Coupon = :coupon';
 $stmt = PDO->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindParam(':coupon', $coupon, DB::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    //query 2
    $query2 = "DELETE FROM serial WHERE Coupon = :coupon";
    $stmt2 = PDO->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':coupon', $coupon, DB::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stmt2->execute()) {
       echo 'Success';
    } else {
       echo 'Unable to Delete';
    }
 } else {
    echo 'Selected Coupon Is Invalid'; 
 }
```

**OR MORE SIMPLY IN ONE QUERY:**

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM serial WHERE coupon = :coupon';
$stmt = PDO->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':coupon', $coupon, DB::PARAM_STR);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  echo 'Success';
} else {
  echo 'failure, invalid coupon';
}
```

Comment: Why would you foist prepared statements on this problem? Prepared statements carry quite a bit of overhead if you are only using them for injection prevention. If you aren't going to reuse the query with multiple sets of parameters, don't use prepared statements.

Comment: I tried to demonstrate how PDO works so that he does not use mysql_* functions. In any case the solution above answers the question user asked.

Comment: The solution sounds very promising, but - `$stmt = PDO->prepare($query)` returns a syntax error `syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`. Plain copy\paste doesn't work. What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Following up from mluebke's answer:

```
// Delete data from mysql
$query="DELETE FROM serial WHERE Coupon = '$coupon'";
mysql_query($query); 

//Did we delete something?
if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
  echo "Bravo!";
}
else{
    "The coupon number you've entered is invalid";
    exit;
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count